# Configure two Routers on one Device

Tags: firewall, router, gateway

I am building a router with a RPi (Raspbian). It has 3 network interfaces:

- **eth0**: Connected to the Internet (IP/Gateway from DHCP)
- **wlan0**, **wlan1**: local WLAN interfaces (each serving its own SSID as AP)

Moreover a have a VPN connection **tun0** to a remote network, which is connected to the internet itself.

Now I want:

- all traffic from **wlan0** to be routed through **tun0** and
- all traffic from **wlan1** to be routed through **eth0**

In the result I want to have two WLANs, one with direct internet access and one with internet access through the VPN connection.

This was very easy using two different devices, but how to do this with only one default gateway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a second routing table and use [policy based routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing).
Applied to your case you need to:

1. Setup the first default route using the main routing table. This table will be used for the traffic generated locally and for the traffic from **wlan1** :

   ```
   ip route add default via <gateway_reachable_by_eth0> table main
   ```
2. Create a second routing table **vpn**:

   ```
   echo 200 vpn >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
   ```
3. Add a default route to the new table:

   ```
   ip route add default via <gateway_reachable_by_tun0> table vpn
   ```
4. Indicate that all traffic from **wlan0** should use this new table:

   ```
   ip rule add from <wlan0_subnet> lookup vpn
   ```

Comment: Is _200_ a freely chosen number?

Comment: @Lukas: Good question, answer is in `man ip-route`: "Route tables: Linux-2.x can pack routes into several routing tables identified by a number in the range from 1 to 2^31 or by name from the file /etc/iproute2/rt_tables .[...].  Values (0, 253, 254, and 255) are reserved for built-in use.